# how to select sibling elements in CSS 3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select element sibling before and after `li.active`.

HTML :

```
<ul class="inline avancement">
  <li>Réception des réponses</li>
  <li class="active">Achat</li>
  <li>Evaluation</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul.avancement li{

padding-right:20px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-left:-4px;
height:37px;
line-height:37px;
}
 li.active ~ li{
    background:url(../img/delimiter_step_left.png) right top no-repeat;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
 li.active + li{
    background:url(../img/delimiter_step_left.png) right top no-repeat;
    background-color:#999999;
}
 ul.avancement li{
    background:url(../img/delimiter_step.png) right top no-repeat;
    background-color:#999999;
    color:white;
}
ul.avancement li.active{
    background:url(../img/delimiter_step_actif.png) right top no-repeat;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
ul.avancement li:last-child{
    background:none;
    background-color:#999999;
}
```

But it doesn't work !

Result :

[image]

I'm waiting red step before active step ! What's wrong ?
thanks

Comment: I think you should look at `:nth-child`

Comment: Sibling selection as you are requesting can't be done with CSS.  There's no sibling selector that works like that.  The only way would be to assign classes to the siblings, or to use jQuery / javascript, or to use nth-child selectors.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS don't tally with your screenshot. Please provide your actual HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select previous element with CSS only solution! Read [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sibling-combinators) if you don't believe me.

However, the next part can be done really easily.

```
.active + li {
    color: red;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkp8z/

Although, your question isn't 100% clear - do you want to select all elements, that are not marked `active`, or only 2 elements that are directly before and next to the active one?